# representation of points of continuity of a function $f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question is  :

[image]

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we need :

for given $\epsilon >0 $ existence of $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$

suppose $x\in A_{j,n}$ for some $j$ then, I have $|f(u)-f(v)|< \frac{1}{n}$ when ever $|u-v| < \frac{1}{j}$

I could not write details neatly but i some how feel that if $x\in A_n$ for all $n$ then I can say $f$ is continuous at $x$

suppose $x\in \cap _{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ :

Now, given $\epsilon > 0 $,  I can always find some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$

Now, I take this $n$ As $x\in A_n$ for some $j$ i would have $x\in A_{j,n}$ for some $j$

i.e., $|f(x)-f(u)|< \frac{1}{n}$ for given $u : |x-u|<\frac{1}{j}$

I take this $\frac{1}{j}$ to be $\delta$ then I am done.

Thus, I would like to conclude that $C= \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$

I would be thankful if some one can help me to rewrite this cumbersome details into compact form (assuming what i have done is correct)

I would be thankful if some one can help me to clear if there is any gaps in the arguments (I am sure there will be some)

Thank you

Comment: To be sure, you have only shown that $C \supseteq \bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$.  You must also show that $C \subseteq \bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$.  What you have done so far, however, does seem correct.

Comment: I have shown $C \supseteq \bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ :O I took $x\in \bigcap _{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n$ and proved it is point of continuity.... :O I did not proved the other way.. I was having trouble only with one way so i thought it would be better if i can ask for clarification of only one way

Comment: Ah.  The other way is indeed a bit easier, so you should be fine.  Just as long as you keep in mind that you eventually do have to show both directions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : Thank you :)

Comment: why down vote???